# How can I open a popup applet in new record mode in Siebel?

Tags: siebel

I'm using Siebel 7.8. I have a list applet with a button which opens a popup form applet, based on the same BC. There are [a few ways of doing this](http://siebelmantra.blogspot.com.es/2013/08/how-to-display-popup-applet-in-siebel.html), in my case I just set the minibutton `MethodInvoked` property to `ShowPopup`.

When I press the button, the popup shows the same data from the record currently selected in the list applet. What I need is, instead of that, to create a new record and show all the fields empty. Just like if the user had pressed "new record" after opening the popup.

I have changed the applet web template `Type` property, from `Edit` to `New` (and I've set accordingly the `Mode` user property on the button). I have also added the following code to the popup applet:

```js
function WebApplet_Load ()
{
  this.BusComp().NewRecord();
}
```

But none of the changes has made any difference, the popup applet is still working exactly like it was doing before (which I find a little weird, at least the `NewRecord()` call should be doing *something*...).

Is there something else I need to change? Or another way to achieve this requeriment?

I know I could create a **virtual business component** for the popup applet, and insert the data in the actual BC when the OK button is pressed. But I think this approach is a bit too much overkill. There must be an easier way to do it, without having to create a VBC+BS. Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you on High Interactivity ? You could try browser script. Try putting this browser script code on Applet_InvokeMethod

```
if (name == "ShowPopup")
  {
    this.InvokeMethod("NewRecord");
    return("ContinueOperation");
  }
```

This even should fire last per Siebel's event sequence. So it should create a new record there.

You could try the same in the Applet_Load event of the browser script.

Comment: Yes, I'm on HI mode. So... `this.InvokeMethod("NewRecord")` instead of `this.BusComp().NewRecord()`? -- My requeriment became more complex than I had anticipated, so I gave up and created a VBC for the popup applet. Anyway, I'm marking this as the accepted answer and will keep it in mind for future reference :)